# System.Text.Json version conflict

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution with 2 projects:

- netcoreapp3.1 Azure Function
- netstandard2.1 library

The netcoreapp3.1 project references the library one. The library project makes use of the `System.Text.Json` APIs. When I build the solution I get the following error:

> Assembly 'System.Text.Json' with identity 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I tried explicitly installing the System.Text.Json 4.7.2 into the netstandard2.1 project.
The app now compiles and works. However, during build process I get a few warnings like this:

> ##[warning]/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2123,5): Warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51". Choosing "System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" arbitrarily.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just explicitly reference a version of the package.

Comment: `System.Text.Json` has changed in .net core 3.0, they made changes some types in the `System.Text.Json` namespace. Also they recommend:
 >Remove the Newtonsoft.Json dependency from .Net Core . Prior to .Net Core 3.x .Net Core had a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json.

And also i see your function uses .net core 5 sdk.


Check [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-next-for-system-text-json/#what-we-shipped-in-net-core-3-0) out.

Comment: From what i've found, that using .Net Core assemblies with .Net class libraries generally dont mix very well, ie on updates you will continue to keep popping up with errors like these. Consider using a .Net Core package instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean by that?

Comment: use `<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="..." />`

Comment: @Batuhan My app is netcoreapp3.1, so it doesn't have Newtonsoft.Json. I have .NET 5 installed on my machine (I also have 3.1). When you build a project, it chooses the latest version automatically, that's why it used .NET 5 to build it.

Comment: @FreekW. What do you mean by .NET core package?

Comment: @DanielA.White I did that, as mentioned in the post. It made the error go away. However, a warning came. I'm not even sure what version I should install. The error mentions `4.2.2.0` and `4.1.2.0`, but there are no versions like that on Nuget!

Comment: just specify the highest version you want to support thats listed.

Comment: If im not mistaken, you are referencing a .Net standard project in your .Net Core project. What im proposing is either building or installing a package from NuGet package manager that uses .Net Core as a foundation which yields the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes visual studio will recommend NuGet packages for an SDK you have installed (like .NET 5) even though your project targets .NET 3.1 like in your case.

Use **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**

[image]

In the manager, you may find that you have packages you can consolidate (so they will use the same version).

[image]

If not, you will have to hunt-and-peck in the manager.  Look for packages that are 5.* instead of 3.1.*.  Also you may find slightly different versions.  try to make them consistent in your solution.

Comment: I didn't have to perform what you describe because I'm past 3.1.  But by running the update all packages from nuget it solved the problem.  So this was a helpful post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is perhaps a better answer.

Downgrade `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` to 3.1.1 as in my screenshot.

Thanks to [this github issue workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23126#issuecomment-672029341).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What helped me.

I had the same nuget package on different projects, but with different build number and when build another project I got this error.

**Just use same version for nugets**

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on this was to downgrade the Nuget Package System.Text.Json.

This in turn downgraded other Nuget packages that depended on it.  I then went back and updated all packages to the most current version.